# How can a subscriber of one publication also be a publisher of another publication in SQL?

Tags: sql, replication

How can a subscriber of one publication also be a publisher of another publication in SQL?

We have a replication on our server which is not initializing because of the following error:
"Cannot drop the table [] because it is being used for replication."

We found out that the client has set the subscriber on their server as a publisher for another replication.

What is the solution to avoid this error?

Thanks

Comment: What's the database? Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, etc.

Comment: All are SQL Databases

Comment: This question seems to be an admin one that could be better answered at dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks, just posted there: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270105/how-can-a-subscriber-of-one-publication-also-be-a-publisher-of-another-publicati